# jieba segmenter applied to "content" column and then create new column "words" with separated characters in r

Tags: r, wordsegment

I am trying to segment chinese sentences from column "content" into words using jieba package in r, and then create a new corresponding column "words" where each row contains the segmented words of the corresponding rows from previous "content" column.

```
df$content (3 rows):
我喜歡吃雞翅；我不喜歡吃雞；哇這是什麼醬做得雞翅？

desired df$words (3 rows):
我 喜歡 吃 雞翅；我 不 喜歡 吃 雞；哇 這 是 什麼 醬 做 得 雞翅？
```

where the words column has 3 corresponding rows with the segmented versions of the content column.

the jieba package does the segmentation of the chinese words well, but i am running into trouble with keeping the segmented words inside 1 row. the jieba segmenter seems to segment all the words of the "content" column, and then treat every word as a separate row. i am really stuck on how to fix this problem - do i need to change the # of vectors recycled?? any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
df$words <- qseg <= df$content
```

Which returns the error:

```
Error: Assigned data `df$words <- qseg <= df$content` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 29175 rows. x Assigned data has 1327701 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
15.
stop(fallback)
14.
signal_abort(cnd)
13.
cnd_signal(error_assign_incompatible_size(nrow, value, j, i_arg, value_arg))
12.
(function (cnd) { cnd_signal(error_assign_incompatible_size(nrow, value, j, i_arg, value_arg)) ...
11.
signalCondition(cnd)
10.
signal_abort(cnd)
9.
abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ...)
8.
stop_vctrs(x_size = x_size, y_size = size, x_arg = x_arg, class = c("vctrs_error_incompatible_size", "vctrs_error_recycle_incompatible_size"))
7.
stop_recycle_incompatible_size(x_size = 1327701L, size = 29175L, x_arg = "")
6.
vec_recycle(value[[j]], nrow)
5.
withCallingHandlers(for (j in seq_along(value)) { if (!is.null(value[[j]])) { value[[j]] <- vec_recycle(value[[j]], nrow) } ...
4.
vectbl_recycle_rhs(value, fast_nrow(x), length(j), i_arg = NULL, value_arg)
3.
tbl_subassign(x, i = NULL, as_string(name), list(value), i_arg = NULL, j_arg = name, value_arg = substitute(value))
2.
`$<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, testing, value = c("网友", "爆料", "网友", "在", "宝鸡", "贴", "吧", "发帖", "称", "有人", "在", "铁路", "门口", "摆放", "花圈", "灵堂", "抗议", "据", "未", "证实", "消息", "说", "期间", "新", "与", ...
1.
`$<-`(`*tmp*`, testing, value = c("网友", "爆料", "网友", "在", "宝鸡", "贴", "吧", "发帖", "称", "有人", "在", "铁路", "门口", "摆放", "花圈", "灵堂", "抗议", "据", "未", "证实", "消息", "说", "期间", "新", "与", "争执", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I made it work! for future people coming across this problem with jieba, use "chinese.misc" package, seg_file() function instead: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chinese.misc/chinese.misc.pdf. it works perfectly with only one line of code! i spent two days frustrated over this and it turns out it was just the faulty jieba package. thank god for the chinese.misc package!